# App crashing when backgrounded

Tags: ios, google-cast, chromecast

my app crashes when sent to background. The console log shows a line `[GCKDeviceScanner stopScanInternal]`. That means it is because of something related to google cast scanner class but I can’t find out the exact reason for the crash. I have also stopped the scan when the app goes into background but still it crashes. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add the full crash report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue and as far as I know, it was because of having multiple instances of `GCKDeviceScanner`. I created `GCKDeviceScanner` a property in `AppDelegate.h` and stopped scanning when app was backgrounded and started scanning again when the app entered foreground.
In `AppDelegate.h`:-

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) GCKDeviceScanner *deviceScanner;
```

In `AppDelegate.m`:-

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  if (self.scanningDevices) {
      [_deviceScanner stopScan];
  }
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  if (self.scanningDevices) {
      [_deviceScanner startScan];
  }
}
```

Here `self.scanningDevices` is a boolean for checking if a scan is under progress. Also make sure that `deviceScanner` **is initialized only once**.